# How to show a graph in a Perl Gtk GUI?

Tags: perl, graph, charts, gtk, gtk3

Using Perl and Gtk2 (or Gtk3), I'd like to display a graph in a GUI application.

Chart::Clicker looks promising, but it seems to only write to files.  Is there a way to get that into a GtkDrawingArea or similar?

Comment: Can you create a [`Cairo`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Cairo)  "context" /  "surface" object and then just write onto it? It's likely more complicated than this, but I'm sure Brian Manning (XAOC  author of GTK and Cairo modules) could provide guidance.  As you work through your project you could write documentation and improve the POD :-)    GPHAT's work on `Chart::Clicker` **is** amazing (GPHAT was inspired by Tufte!)  but as [GPHAT himself points out](http://www.onemogin.com/observability/charting/a-chart-is-worth-some-words.html) a lot of the action in charting is now  "client side".

Comment: The other bonus would be you could come to SO with more specific questions to do with your code and get more specific and helpful responses.  These are comments so they get a pass on being very helpful ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After lots of experimentation, I figured it out.

1. Don't use Gtk::DrawingArea, use Gtk::Image.
2. $img->set_from_surface($chart->driver->surface);

Reading through the source to Chart::Clicker, I found that $chart->driver is the Cairo object and ->surface is the actual Cairo surface.  A Gtk::Image can be directly drawn based on a Cairo surface.

Complete program that illustrates how to do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Gtk3 -init;
use Chart::Clicker;
use Chart::Clicker::Data::Series;
use Chart::Clicker::Data::DataSet;
my $win = Gtk3::Window->new;
my $img = Gtk3::Image->new;
$win->add($img);
my $chart = Chart::Clicker->new;
my $dataset = Chart::Clicker::Data::DataSet->new(
        series => [Chart::Clicker::Data::Series->new(
                keys => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                values => [2, 3, 5, 7, 11],
        )],
);
$chart->add_to_datasets($dataset);
$chart->draw;
$img->set_from_surface($chart->driver->surface);
$win->signal_connect(destroy => sub{Gtk3->main_quit});
$win->show_all;
Gtk3::main;
```

**Update**

On Gtk3 < 3.10, replace the line containing `set_from_surface` with:

```
my $loader = Gtk3::Gdk::PixbufLoader->new;
$chart->driver->surface->write_to_png_stream(sub {
    $loader->write([unpack 'C*', $_[1]]);
});
$loader->close;
$img->set_from_pixbuf($loader->get_pixbuf);
```

Comment: The set_from_surface() method was introduced in Gtk 3.10.  RHEL 7 only has Gtk 3.8.8 so this sample doesn't work there.